# Docker of mix release crashes with "Exec format error"

Tags: docker, elixir, release, elixir-mix

### Background

I have an executable created via `mix release` which works just fine when I run it with `start` on my local machine. However, my docker image crashes when trying to `start` the executable and I don't know why.

### Docker

```
FROM elixir:1.10

# Install Hex + Rebar
RUN mix do local.hex --force, local.rebar --force

COPY . /
WORKDIR /

ENV MIX_ENV=prod
RUN mix do deps.get --only $MIX_ENV, deps.compile
RUN mix release

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT=8080
ENV SHELL=/bin/bash

CMD ["_build/prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app", "start"]
```

This is my docker file. It does nothing special other than compiling and then trying to run the release via `start`.

### Error

However, when I execute the docker image with  `docker run -p 8080:8080 my-app:1.0` docker crashes:

```
/_build/prod/rel/my_app/releases/0.1.0/../../erts-10.5/bin/erl: 12: exec: /_build/prod/rel/my_app/erts-10.5/bin/erlexec: Exec format error
```

### Research

At first I thought this was happening because the file `_build/prod/rel/my_app/bin/my_app` was missing `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the top (after reading some SO questions).

While indeed it doesn't have that, it has something else that should equally work: `#!/bin/sh`

So this theory is out.

### Question

Is something wrong with my Dockerfile?
How can I get rid this error?

Comment: could `ENV SHELL=/bin/bash` require bash instead of `#!/bin/sh` ?

Comment: Not sure if it's the case here, but have you added `/_build/` to the .dockerignore file? I remember some time ago having problems mixing build files from development machine (mac) and inside docker (linux).

Comment: it looks like a problem with the architecture used to create the image and the architecture used to run the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### RCA

This was a tricky one. After reading other similar questions (and the comments from @potibas and @Stefano) I found out what was happening.

So, as I have said, the release file works well on my *local* machine. This happens because in my *local* machine the files were being compiled to its operative system (OS).

Now, the docker VM does not have the same OS as my local machine. This matters because of this line:

`COPY . /`

Here I am copying **everything** from the workdir to docker. Including the binaries and dependencies **compiled for my local machine's OS**.

This caused the issue above mentioned.

### Solution

There are 2 possible solutions.

1. Remove the `_build` and `deps` folders from the image after the `COPY` command, via `RUN rm -r _build` and `RUN rm -r deps/`.
2. Add the mentioned folders as well as all the non-essential files to a `.dockerignore` file.

I personally opted for the second option, as it allows me to have a leaner image.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I used the `.dockerignore` approach as well. I can add that you could also specifically cherry pick folders to `COPY` - might result in a less "lean" Dockerfile, but you have all the control.